# Replace a string or nothing in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace `"metre"` or `"mt"` with `"m"` using perl. How to do this? I was using this:

```
$string=~ s/[Mm][Ee\s][Tt][Rr\s][Ee\s]/m/g;
```

It is working for `"metre"`, but not for `"mt"`

Comment: Why not just `s/m(etre|t)/m/gi`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `i` [modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) lets you do a case-insensitive match.

```
$string =~ s/metre|mt/m/gi;
```

or

```
$string =~ s/m(?:etre|t)/m/gi;
```

, which is more efficient.

Assuming that you are trying to replace the "word" `metre` or `mt`, a unit of length, to `m`, you would want to use the [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) meta character `\b`, like @M42 pointed out in the comments. This will prevent matches like `mt` in `warmth`.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply

Comment: +1, but it's better to use word boundary ie. `\bm(?:etre|t)\b` to avoid unwanted replaces.

Comment: +1, and I doubt if there's any point in optimising this but the second version is about three times faster than the first.

Comment: @M42: The trailing `\b` maybe, but there are likely to be strings like `42mt` which wouldn't be found with the leading one. Perhaps `s/(?<![a-z])m(?:etre|t)\b/m/gi`

Comment: @Borodin Hmm, is the negative lookbehind part necessary?

Comment: @Borodin Never mind, it is necessary in order not to match to something like `dreamt`.

Comment: *"which is more efficient"*, how exactly? Perl re probably builds a trie out of both these, in which case it would be the same. But I'm just speculating, it's better to look at the output of `use re 'debug';` if you care about such details.

Comment: @Qtax There are 2 things that make it more efficient. 1, using `(?:...)` prevents capture. 2, `m(etre|t)` allows the regex engine to stop its matching trial when the first character is not `m`. For `metre|mt`, the regex engine tries the `mt` after failing on the first `m` in `metre`. I suspect the OP cares much about the efficiency, but I added it just for the heck of it :)

Comment: @NigoroJr, that's the naive implementation of a regex engine. In reality Perl does a lot more and all kinds of optimizations. The compiled regex for both of these expression uses a trie and *is exactly the same* (on my Perl 5.16.3 at least). See for your self: `perl -E 'use re "debug"; /metre|mt/; /m(?:etre|t)/;'`

Comment: @Qtax You are absolutely right! The time difference when I did the benchmark, I guess, was caused by the time difference in *compiling* the regex. I was surprised by the fact that the results were a dead-on match and also that Perl was smart enough to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string =~ s{metre|mt}{m}ig;
```

**Explanation:**
**$string**      = your string 
**s**            = replace
**{metre|mt}**   =old content
**{m}**          =replace content
**i**            =ignore case
**g**            =do this action globally